# How to assign a function as a return type from function in Scala

Tags: function, scala, return-type

I'm very new to Scala and I have run in to a problem.

I am trying to write a class which will hold a queue of functions. I want to be able to add functions to the queue, and when all functions have been added, run these. Essentially build an expression like: "function1(function2(function3()))" to be returned and then evaluated. This is the code I've got so far:

```
  class Pipeline() {

    // Queue of functions to run
    private var queue: Queue[ _ => _] = new LinkedList();

    // Add functions to the queue 
    def addFunction(func:_ => _ ): Unit ={
      queue.add(func)
    }

    // Run all the functions in the queue
    def run(): Unit = {
      val function = runHelper(queue.poll(), queue)
      function
    }

    def runHelper(func: _ => _, queue: Queue[_ => _]): _  = {
      // Recursion base case
      if(queue.isEmpty)
        return func
      // Keep building the function recursively
      else
        func(runHelper(queue.poll(), queue))        
    }    
  }
```

I'm sure that here is more than one error in there. But right now, what I'm stuck at is the return type of the runHelper function. As you can see I'm trying to use the _ wildcard, but this gives a compilation error. How would I defined that the function will return a function? And am I going about this in a good way - if not please point me in the direction of a more suitable solution to the problem.

**edit1: Clarification**
The input and return type of the functions are not known beforehand, and they their sequence needs to be possible to assign dynamically.

**Edit2: More problems**
I've been trying to get the code Edmondo1984 suggested to work the way I want it to, but I can't seem to get it.

What I need to do would be something like this:

```
val func1: String => File = function1
val func2: File => File = function2

var queue = func1

if(runFunc2)
    queue = queue :: func2

queue("exampleString")
```

What I specifically need to know is how to be able to do the "queue = queue :: func2". Since :: returns a FunctionQueue, I would have imagined that I would be able to assign it to the queue variable. But then again, I guess that since the first initialization of the variable leads to it having the "String => File" demand. I feel like I'm in a bit over my head here, and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the sequence of functions known in advance or constructed dynamically? If the former then Jan's answer is the way to go.

Comment: The sequence is constructed dynamically. So right now I'm guessing that Edmondo1984s answer is the way to go. But I'm still trying to wrap my mind around it.

Comment: Are they endofunctions? That is, is the input type equal to the return type, and, therefore, all functions share the same type?

Comment: @Daniel Unfortunately they are not endofunctions. The input type and output type will not always be the same.

Comment: Remember that methods ending in `:` are right-associative! So you need `func2 :: queue`.

Comment: Can you post a small gist with the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible because _ is a placeholder for an existential type: A type which exists but is not currently relevant: you can use that for example when you want to print a list like the following:

```
scala>  def aMethod(a:List[_]) = println(a.size)
aMethod: (a: List[_])Unit

scala>  val b = List(2,3,4)
b: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)

scala>  aMethod(b)
3
```

This works because in fact you do not make access to the elements of the list, so you can imagine you do not need their class.

Because Scala is a strongly typed language, i.e. the compiler checks that the signatures are respected in your code.  A Queue[ _ => _]  is a queue of function from an unknown type to an unknown type and it is not useful, because if you try to pop a function and apply it to an input parameter, you won't be able to verify if that input parameter matches the signature.

What you are trying to do is not trivial, and you need to define your queue in a recursive way. You might want to read Shapeless HLIST implementation, but the idea is the following :

```
trait FunctionQueue[A,B]{

  def ::[C](newFunction: C => A): FunctionQueue[C,B]

  def apply(a:A):B
}

class FunctionQueueImpl[A,B,C](val f:A=>B, val queue:FunctionQueue[B,C]) extends FunctionQueue[A,C]{

  def apply(a:A) = queue.apply(f(a))

  def ::[D](newFunction: (D) => A):FunctionQueue[D,C] = new FunctionQueueImpl[D,A,C](newFunction,this)
}

object FunctionQueue {
  def EmptyQueue[T]:FunctionQueue[T,T] = new FunctionQueue[T,T] {
    def ::[C](newFunction: (C) => T):FunctionQueue[C,T] = new FunctionQueueImpl[C,T,T](newFunction,this)

    def apply(a: T):T = a
  }

  implicit def functionToQueue[A,B](function:A => B):FunctionQueue[A,B] = new FunctionQueueImpl(function, EmptyQueue[B])
}
```

Now you can try it in the repl:

```
scala>  import FunctionQueue._
import FunctionQueue._

scala>  val a: Int => Int = _ * 10
a: Int => Int = <function1>


scala>  val b: Double => Int = _.toInt 
b: Double => Int = <function1>

scala>  val c : String => Double = _.toDouble
c: String => Double = <function1>

scala>  val queue = c::b::a
queue: FunctionQueue[String,Int] = FunctionQueueImpl@cccfa5e

scala>  queue("1.25")
res1: Int = 10

scala>  queue("3.25")
res2: Int = 30
```

I would suggest reading Miles Sabins work to understand more.

Comment: That's nice, but if we know the sequence of functions up front, as we do in your example, then we could more easily write (a compose b compose c)("1.25"). shapeless is not the only hammer ;-)

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking to do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems I was wrong in my previous statement. I still don't understand how to do what I want with this. See the question for more details.

Answer (score 3):

The form I prefer for functions is: `(parameter list) => returnType`.

Here is what I think your code should look like. My IDE likes it, but that's no guarantee:

```
class Pipeline[T]() {

 // Queue of functions to run
 private var queue: util.Queue[ (T) => T] = new util.LinkedList()

 // Add functions to the queue
 def addFunction(func: (T)=> T ) {
   queue.add(func)
 }

 // Run all the functions in the queue
 def run() {
   val function = runHelper(queue.poll(), queue)
   function
 }

 def runHelper(func: (T) => T, queue: util.Queue[(T)=> T ]): (T)=>T = {
   // Recursion base case
   if(queue.isEmpty)
     func
   // Keep building the function recursively
   else
     func compose runHelper(queue.poll(), queue)
  }
}
```

Comment: Using this code I guess I would have set the type T as I declare a new Pipeline instance. This would however not help me since I will have different inputs and outputs for the different functions. Still helpful for my understanding of Scala, though. :)

Comment: Remember, Scala is typesafe so there's a limit on how wild you can get. I don't know that you would be able to create a pipeline that would allow you to compose, for example one function (Int)=>String with (String)=>Double. Yes, they're composable because the output of the one is the input of the other, but you're not going to be able to do that using something akin to your `Pipeline`.

Comment: "but you're not going to be able to do that using something akin to your Pipeline" - I thing you are absolutely right there.  My current guess is that I need to do something along the lines of what @Edmondo1984 suggested in his answer. Thank you very much for taking the time look at this. I would vote you up, but I don't have enough rep to do so I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

You could give function composition a try. For example like this.

```
val f = (x:Int) => 2 * x
val g = f.compose(f)
```

if the in and output types vary you have to take care that in and output match...

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the implementation, you can use a simple `List` of functions `T => T` (which are called endofunctions).

Now, in scalaz you have an instance of a `Monoid` (built from [`Semigroup`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Semigroup.scala#L163) and [`Zero`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Zero.scala#L141)) for such functions. This means, you can write the following code:

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> val f = ((_:Int) + 6).endo
f: scalaz.Endo[Int] = <function1>

scala> val g = ((_:Int) * 4).endo
g: scalaz.Endo[Int] = <function1>

scala> val h = (-(_:Int)).endo
h: scalaz.Endo[Int] = <function1>

scala> f :: g :: h :: nil
res3: List[scalaz.Endo[Int]] = List(<function1>, <function1>, <function1>)

scala> .asMA.sum
res4: scalaz.Endo[Int] = <function1>

scala> f(g(h(1)))
res5: Int = 2

scala> res4(1)
res6: Int = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type of a function like so:

```
Function[T, T]
```

or

```
T => T
```

Assuming both input and output of your function are equal, which they really should be. You’d have to specify or replace `T` of course.

If you really have variadic input–output, the whole scheme will become much more complicated.

Comment: That is the problem - the input and output type of the functions can vary. Is there any way to accomplish this? My intuition was to use the wildcards for this purpose, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I’d go by immutable structures and composition then (using `compose` or `andThen`).